# jQuery Scroll, when Scroll to bottom always show duplicate data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery Function Scroll. When I put the scroll in bottom then refresh the page, it will load data duplicate.

Please see my JS below:

```
var track_load = 0;
var loading  = false;
var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>;

$('#content').load("../load_post_photo.php", {'group_no':track_load,'q_uid':'<?php echo $q_uid; ?>'}, function() {track_load++; $('.animation_image').hide();});

$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
    {
        if(track_load < total_groups && loading==false)
        {
            loading = true;
            $('.animation_image').show();

            $.post('../load_post_photo.php',{'group_no':track_load,'q_uid':'<?php echo $q_uid; ?>'}, function(data){

            $("#content").append(data);
            load = 1;
            $('.animation_image').hide();

            track_load++;
            loading = false; 

    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
        $('.animation_image').hide();
        loading = false;
    });
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here has an async `.load` happening on the initial page load and then again with a `.post` tied in to the scroll event.

To answer your question about why when you move it "to the bottom" it loads twice, this is most likely being caused by where you place the code in the head. If jQuery isn't loaded yet, that JS is going to error out on you (check the console) the first time. However, when you move the code "to the bottom" (most likely after the reference to jQuery) the initial async call for `.load` is working.

Now...

You really should reconsider the way you have your event set up there for the scroll. You should consider employing [throttling](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle) if you continue using that approach for determining when to post whatever data it is you are handling.

For an example of throttling, fire up your console in your favorite browser developer tools and check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/81579thy/. The code that really matters is below.

```
var myFunc = _.throttle( function () {
    // body of my function
}, 750 );
```

This example uses lodash's implementation of a `throttle` method (linked to above). What this does is essentially takes the function you give it and returns you a new one that will only execute after the millisecond "wait" timer you pass as your second argument.

If you follow the link to the fiddle and open your console, you'll see the logs come through where the throttled function is called more than it is actually invoked.

Comment: Hi... Any example of that? Confused

Comment: Added some more info around throttling. I'm thinking that's where you're confused. If you provide more info in your question myself or others can help you out better and faster too!